# BigQuery billing. How 10 GB free quote exactly works?

Tags: google-bigquery

On BigQuery pricing page it is said "First 10 GB is free each month, see Storage pricing for details.". Does it mean that:
 
- each month i can load <10 GB of data into tables and don't get billed at all

Example for three months:

```
12 = 12 - 10 = 2 - i get billed for 2 GB
12 + 9 = 12 - 10 + 9 - 10 = 2 + 0 = 2 - i get billed for 2 GB
12 + 9 + 14 = 12 - 10 + 9 - 10 + 14 - 10 = 2 + 0 + 4 = 6 - i get billed for 6 GB.
```

- each month i don't pay for 10 GB from summed table size.

Example for three months:

```
12 = 12 - 10 = 2 - i get billed for 2 GB
12 + 9 = 12 + 9 - 10 = 11 - i get billed for 11 GB
12 + 9 + 14 = 12 + 9 + 14 - 10 = 25 - i get billed for 25 GB
```

All other aspects of billing are described pretty clear but this is a bit confusing to me (i am not a native english speaker)
Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter how much data is loaded each month. What matters is the total amount of data stored in BigQuery. If you have 10GB or less of data stored in BigQuery, then there is no cost. If you have more than 10GB, then you pay $0.02 (or an equivalent local rate) per GB per month for any data stored in addition to the first 10GB.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Elliott Brossard : What's about query calculator? Is the same?

Comment: @Loint you could submit a separate question if something is confusing about query cost calculations.